# Why can't I access subclass type for my Django model instances?

Tags: django, python-3.x, oop

I have something like this:

```
class Cat(models.Model):
    #some fields
class SiameseCat(Cat):
    #some additional fields

for cat in pet_store.cats.all(): 
    print(isinstance(cat, SiameseCat))
    print(type(cat))
```

Even when my instantiated SiameseCats are visible under a separate heading on the django admin page, I always get "False, Cat" printed to the terminal for each cat in the pet store. If I try to `print(cat.siamese_only_field)`, I get an attribute error.

I need to access and output the siamese_only_field for my project to work. Also, this whole thing is generally a head scratcher and I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong. Why can't I access the model subclass of an object as expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django implements subclassing of models by adding an (implicit) `OneToOneField` to the child model `SiameseCat` that refers to the `Cat`.

You can thus aim to access the `SiameseCat` model with:

```
for cat in pet_store.cats.all():
    try:
        siamese_cat = cat.siamesecat
        print('siamese_cat')
    except SiameseCat.DoesNotExist:
        print('simple cat')
```

You can boost the efficiency of this approach by using `.select_related('siamesecat')` to load the siamese cat objects in the same query:

```
for cat in pet_store.cats.select_related('siamesecat'):
    try:
        siamese_cat = cat.siamesecat
        print('siamese_cat')
    except SiameseCat.DoesNotExist:
        print('simple cat')
```

A relational database is not well-design for subclassing. ORM's try to implement this, but often it is not really a good idea to use subclassing, unless there are no other simple modeling solutions.